# Border not appearing in converting HTML to PDF using Iron PDF

Tags: html, pdf

I am trying to convert an HTML document to PDF using Iron PDF for border on every page(top and bottom) but the border is generating only on first page and last page. I have tried my option by referring to google but still no luck.

**Any solution please ?**

Comment: were you able to find an answer for this.

Answer (score 0):

We use IronPDF .NET application development extensively.  It closely matches the exact behavior of the Chrome web browser since Sept 2021 which has made an enormous difference.

This tutorial helped me debug my html.

- https://ironpdf.com/tutorials/pixel-perfect-html-to-pdf/

Another approach would be to the the HTML Header/Footer on each page to achieve this.  As of 2021.9 Ironpdf you may even have
HTMLHeaderFooters and Text based headers and Footers on the same page:
https://ironpdf.com/examples/html-headers-and-footers/

```
// PM> Install-Package IronPdf
using IronPdf;


IronPdf.ChromePdfRenderer Renderer = new IronPdf.ChromePdfRenderer();


// Build a footer using html to style the text
// mergeable fields are:
// {page} {total-pages} {url} {date} {time} {html-title} & {pdf-title}
Renderer.RenderingOptions.HtmlHeader = new HtmlHeaderFooter()
{
    
   HtmlFragment = "<center><i>{page} of {total-pages}<i></center><hr/>",
   DrawDividerLine = true
};

Renderer.RenderingOptions.HtmlFooter = new HtmlHeaderFooter()
{
    
   HtmlFragment = "<hr/><b>Footer (C)2021 Steph the Honey Badger<b>",
   DrawDividerLine = true
};
```